# PHP Trying to get Order ID in WooCommerce Api 2.0.1 create order function

Tags: php, arrays, api, object, woocommerce

I create an order using WooCommerce API and it works great.

This is what I get doing **`print_r($client->orders->create($data)`**.

```
stdClass Object
  (
     [order]=> stdClass Object
       (
        [id]=> 817
        [order_number]=> 817
        [created_at]=> 2016-06-15T14:23:30Z
        [updated_at]=> 2016-06-15T14:23:30Z
        [completed_at]=> 2016-06-15T14:23:30Z
        [status]=> pending
        [currency]=> EUR
        [total]=> 0.00
        [subtotal]=> 0.00
        [total_line_items_quantity]=> 3
        [total_tax]=> 0.00
        [total_shipping]=> 0.00
        [cart_tax]=> 0.00
        [shipping_tax]=> 0.00
        [total_discount]=> 0.00
        [shipping_methods]=> Free Shipping
        [payment_details]=> stdClass Object
           (
              [method_id]=> paypal
              [method_title]=> PayPal and Credit Cards
              [paid]=> 
           )
        [billing_address]=> stdClass Object
           (
```

I'm trying to get `id` value.

I call this funtion to create an order `print_r($client->orders->create($data);`
where `$data` is an array with order details.

Tried this method but doesn't work:

```
$object = print_r($client->orders->create($data), true);
echo $object->order->id;
```

I used this [API](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library)

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once( 'lib/woocommerce-api.php' );
$options = array(
    'debug'           => true,
    'return_as_array' => true,
    'validate_url'    => false,
    'timeout'         => 30,
    'ssl_verify'      => false,
);

$data = array(
    'order' => array(
        'payment_details' => array(
            'method_id' => 'paypal',
            'method_title' => 'PayPal and Credit Cards',
            'paid' => false
        ),
        'billing_address' => array(
            'first_name' => 'name',
            'last_name' => 'surname',
            'company' => '',
            'address_1' => 'address',
            'address_2' => '',
            'city' => 'city',
            'state' => 'state',
            'postcode' => 'cap',
            'country' => 'UK',
            'email' => 'email',
            'phone' => 'phone'
        ),
        'shipping_address' => array(
            'first_name' => 'name',
            'last_name' => 'surname',
            'company' => '',
            'address_1' => 'address',
            'address_2' => '',
            'city' => 'city',
            'state' => 'state',
            'postcode' => 'cap',
            'country' => 'UK'
        ),
        'customer_id' => 0,
        'line_items' => array(
            array(
                'product_id' => 871,
                'quantity' => 1
            )
        ),
        'shipping_lines' => array(
            array(
                'method_id' => 'free_shipping',
                'method_title' => 'Free Shipping',
                'total' => 0.00
            )
        )
    )
);

try {

    $client = new WC_API_Client( 'http://my-site.com', '#####', '#####', $options );

    $object = print_r( $client->orders->create( $data ), true );
    echo $object['order']['id'];

} catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;
    if ( $e instanceof WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception ) {
        print_r( $e->get_request() );
        print_r( $e->get_response() );
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: echo $nameofyourobjectarray -> order -> id;

Comment: if you read my question I've already tried **`echo $nameofyourobjectarray -> order -> id;`**

Comment: Is the array above what you get when you print_r $object?

Comment: I don't understand your comment but I added **`$data`** content

Comment: If you do print_r($object) what do you get?

Comment: Get **`stdClass Object ( [order] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 817 [order_number] => 817`** ecc. like in the question

Comment: did you get any error message when you did echo $object->order->id;?

Comment: try this for testing 
$test=json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
echo $test['order']['id'];

Comment: With **`echo $object->order->id;`** get nothing. With **`echo $test['order']['id'];`** get **`s`** printed on screen

Comment: $test=json_decode(json_encode($object), true);  print_r($test); can you copy and paste the result of this print_r?

Comment: Get stdClass Object ( [order] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 817 [order_number] => 817 ecc.

Comment: objects in $test????? how did that happen? @@

Comment: Do this one last time $test=json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
$test2=json_decode(json_encode($test), true);
print_r($test2); if you still don't see a normal associative array without the object notation then I don't know what it is.

Comment: Tried **`$object = print_r( $client->orders->create( $data ), true ); $test=json_decode(json_encode($object), true); $test2=json_decode(json_encode($test), true); print_r($test2);`** and get the same

Comment: what about changing the options of reut
require_once( 'lib/woocommerce-api.php' );

$options = array(
    'ssl_verify'      => false, return_as_array' =>true,
);

Comment: Changed and with **`echo $object->order->id;`** get nothing. With **`echo $test['order']['id'];`** get **`A`** printed on screen. With **`$test=json_decode(json_encode($object), true); $test2=json_decode(json_encode($test), true); print_r($test2);`** get the same

Comment: no no, if you changed the option, $object itself should be an array, just print_r($object) and see what you get first.

Comment: Get **`Array ( [order] => Array ( [id] => 817 [order_number] => 817`**

Comment: and you get a letter `A` on screen if you do echo $object['order']['id']; ??? this doesn't make sense at all....

Comment: can you post your full php code in the question?

Comment: 'first_name' => name, is name meant to be a string? If so shouldn't all the strings be enclosed in single quotes?

Comment: Now it's like my code. It's all String

Comment: $object['order']['id'] still returns 'A' right?

Comment: Yes, still reurns 'A'

Answer (score 0):

These lines worked for me:

```
$result = get_object_vars( $client->orders->create($data) );
echo( get_object_vars(array_values($result)[0])['id'] );
```